# How do I access the ItemPanel programmatically?

Tags: wpf

How do I access the listviews panel in code behind?

Xaml definition:

```
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <telerik:RadCarouselPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

If I name the panel, I get a compile-time error when refering to it in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to store the RadCarouselPanel when it is loaded

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <telerik:RadCarouselPanel Loaded="RadCarouselPanel_Loaded"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

and in code behind

```
private RadCarouselPanel m_radCarouselPanel = null;

private void RadCarouselPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    m_radCarouselPanel = sender as RadCarouselPanel;
}
```